# Error when sending mail ASP.NET (Works fine on my machine, error is only on host)

Tags: .net

I need to send a mail in this asp.net app and when im running the app on visual studio it works fine but in the server it gives me an error, can someone help me?

Error:
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx

This is the code i'm using:

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
mail.To.Add(@MAIL);
mail.From = new MailAddress("xxxx@myDomain.com");
mail.Subject = "Subject";
mail.Body = txtBody.Text;
mail.IsBodyHtml = false;
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
smtp.Host = "smtpout.secureserver.net";
smtp.Port = 25;
smtp.EnableSsl = false;
smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(
    "XXXXXXXXX@mydomain.com",        
    "XXXXXXXXX");
smtp.Send(mail);
```

I've already use the 3 ports godaddy website gives you (25, 80, 3535) and the same thing happens

Comment: Just one little question: WHICH ERROR?

Comment: Are you sure that it is a good idea to post your password here?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, hosting providers will not allow you to use their SMTP services cross domain. Can you try using another public SMTP service like google? [Follow the instructions on their web site.](https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=12103&ctx=mail)
This will make sure it's not your code, but the problem is in your smtp provider.
Also, post the exception that you are getting. That usually helps.

Comment: google accounts need ssl right?   my server does not support ssl

Comment: That is correct, but I'm sure you can find another server to test it out. My answer was directed towards exploring that option.